# How to remove arrows from views Select list field

Tags: views

I have a content type which has a select list field.

I created a view where select list field was added under "filter criteria".

[image]

How can I remove the arrows and slider?

Comment: Hello - that's just the default styling of a multi-value html select widget. It's not a special Drupal thing. You could install a theme that styles select widgets differently or create a new (or modify your existing) custom theme to style it differently.

Answer (score 1):

The appearance of the Select widget on a Content type can be changed on the `Manage form display` page for that Content type (for example for Article CT it's under `Structure > Content types > Article > Manage form display` (`/admin/structure/types/manage/article/form-display`)).

For a List field you can change it from the `Select list` to `Check boxes/radio buttons`.

There are also modules that provide different widgets for these types of fields, for example [Select 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/select2).

---

In Views you can change how each of the Exposed form elements is rendered under Advanced (third column area) > `Exposed form style` settings.

The module [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) is commonly used to adjust the Views Exposed forms.